# Converting a [String: String] dictionary to an unescaped string

Tags: ios, swift

I need to pass a String representation of a `[String: String]` dict into a C library.

```
var block: [String: String] = [:]
block["type"] = "open"
block["source"] = "A59A25991"
block["account"] = "1231"
block["work"] = "0"
block["signature"] = "0"
```

I'm trying to send in a value that looks like this:

```
"{
    "type": "open",
    "source": keyOfPendingBlock,
    "representative:" anotherAccountList,
    "account": myAddress,
    "work": "0",
    "signature": "0"

}"
```

`block.description` escapes, so does doing:

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: block, options: .prettyPrinted)
if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { ... }
```

How can I get this value without escaping? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with *escaping*? The displayed backslashes are virtual and `.prettyPrinted` adds a needless bunch of whitespace and newline characters.

Comment: Yeah, by escaping I meant the newlines and backslashes that I see when I print in the console. Want to make sure I'm not sending those new lines and backslashes in as part of the string

Comment: Delete `, options: .prettyPrinted`

Comment: Removed that. I still see the backslashes in my console. Is that just a side effect of the console or are those backslashes being sent in as well

Comment: @ZackShapiro just remove `.prettyPrinted`, that's what adds the extra newlines. Btw did you actually test your code? As vadian mentioned before, those backslashes are just there for printing and are not actually part of the string, so your code should work fine. Checking the value in a playground could also help, there will be no virtual blackslashes in the preview unlike the console output.

Comment: The backslashed are virtual, that means they are added to be able to display double quotes in a literal string. They will **not** being sent.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tested in a playground and then in a console so I was surprised when the backslashes showed up in console. No backslashes in the console

Answer (score 0):

Use `let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: block, options: [])`

The `prettyPrinted` option is adding the newline characters and whitespace.